# How to find out total running time of system and hard disk?

Tags: logging, time

I have a sony laptop with windows 7. I bought it four years ago and i have used it with vista, ubuntu and leopard also.

How to find out the total on time of the system since i bought it?

Any way to find out the total ontime of the hard disk? ( I have heard the total ontime of the hard disk is stored somewhere in it).

How about the total data passing through my ethernet port?

(Are these data too much to ask? :P )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your hard disk's [SMART data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology), e.g. using [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki). I think the total running time is in there, but since the disk might be able to spin down while the machine is running, it's probably not accurate.