# How to get total running time of a hard disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos

In order to do disk rotation in a server, I need to know the current running time (online) time of a disk on a Linux CentOS release 6.3 (Final) system.

The disks are connected with SATA (e.g. /dev/sdc), are simple rotating type (Western Digital RE type disks), and are not organized in any RAID or similar.

I have tried to find it using `smartctl` (as suggested in [How to find out total running time of system and hard disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/279412)), but was unable to find the information.  Any suggestion for command ?

Comment: What do you mean you get no luck when running smartctrl?  Do you get errors or what?  **How are the disks physically connected?**  Do you have a hardware RAID controller?  You might not have an easy way to access any data with harware RAID.  You really need to provide more details.

Comment: So what output do you get for `smartctl --all /dev/sdc`?  You should see a section labeled `Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds`.  Do you see any values there?  What exactly did you get?

Comment: Yes, thanks, found it, I assume it is "Power_On_Hours".  Will update the post with result.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Answer based on comments from @Zoredache:

Command is `smartctl --all /dev/sdc` and the section to look under is "Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds", which has an attribute named "Power_On_Hours".

So command for just getting power on hours (runnning) is:

```
smartctl --all /dev/sdc | grep Power_On_Hours
```

Which can then show something like:

```
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       10171
```

The running time is thus: 10171 hours

Comment: But in TOSHIBA MK3276GSX model this is not defined as Power_On_Hours. It is Power_On_Minutes or Loaded_Hours

Answer (score 1):

If You put in NAGIOS check, You could do :

```
smartctl --all /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours | cut -d "-" -f2 | tr -d "[:blank:]"
```

On this way You don't waste time, connecting on server via ssh for example and typing command over and over.

Also, there is hdsentinel script, where You have `Power on time` row. There is example:

```
./HDSentinel | grep Power
```

Output should look like

```
Power on time: 1223 days, 16 hours
```

I generally prefer HDSentinel script, because it have HDD Health output. Smartctl is much more harder to analyze in term of Hard disk health, than hdsentinel.

Comment: Hard Disk Sentinel Linux Edition (FREE): https://www.hdsentinel.com/hard_disk_sentinel_linux.php; Linux scripts: https://www.hdsentinel.com/add-on-linux-scripts.php